# Magento getSingleton confusion

Tags: magento

I'm a little confused about calls I see to `Mage::getSingleton`, and I'm hoping someone can help me understand a little better.

I have seen a piece of core code that does this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
```

I don't know PHP, but I think I can make a safe assumption from the **getSingleton** method name that there will be only one instance of the class specified (the class being specified as a grouped class name, and resolving to `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Session.php` - containing class `Mage_Customer_Model_Session`.

**Question 1** -

How did the getSingleton method know to look in the Model folder for the class?

**Question 2** -

So there is one instance of the class for the whole ... I want to say JVM as I am from a Java background, but I'll say PHP engine in the hope that that is vaguely the correct terminology; the `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` is not passed in a customer id or any such identifier, yet we call the method `isLoggedIn()`! Give there is not a `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` instance per customer, how can we ask a singleton if a customer is logged in when we do not tell it what customer we are talking about?

**Question 3** -

I've seen calls to `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')` and to `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')` - what is the difference?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

First, before we get to Magento, it's important to understand that PHP has a radically different process model than Java.  A PHP singleton (regardless of Magento's involvement) is a single instance of a class **per HTTP Request**.  A PHP program isn't persistent in memory the same way a Java program is, so adjust your expectations of a "singleton" accordingly.

Next, it's important to understand that Magento is a framework built **on top** of PHP, using PHP, and in many cases the original Magento developers wanted to push things towards a more Java like architecture.  So, you're going to see things that look familiar, are familiar, but likely differ in some major way from what you're used to because they still need to hew to PHP's version of the universe.

Magento uses a factory pattern to instantiate Helpers, Blocks, and "Model" classes.  The string

```
core/session
```

is a class alias.  This alias is used to lookup a class name in Magento's configuration. In short, this string is converted into path expressions that search Magento's configuration files to derive a classname, based on the context (helper, block, model) it was called in. For a longer version, see my [Magento's Class Instantiation Autoload](http://alanstorm.com/magento_class_abstration_autoload) article.

The concept of a "Model" is a little fuzzy in Magento.  In some cases models are used as domain, or service models.  In other cases they're used as a more traditional middleware database persistence models.  After working with the system for a few years, I think the safest way to think about Models is they're Magento's attempt to do away with direct class instantiation.

There's two ways to instantiate a model class.

```
Mage::getModel('groupname/classname');
Mage::getSingleton('groupname/classname');
```

The first form will get you a new class instance.  The second form will get you a singleton class instance.  This particular Magento abstraction allows you to create a singleton out of **any** Magento model class, but only if you stick to Magento's instantiation methods.  That is, if you call

```
Mage::getSingleton('groupname/classname');
```

then subsequent calls to

```
Mage::getSingleton('groupname/classname');
```

will return that singleton instance.  (This is implemented with a registry pattern). However, there's nothing stopping you from directly instantiating a new instance of the class with either

```
$o = Mage::getModel('groupname/classname');
$o = new Mage_Groupname_Model_Classname();
```

Which brings us to sessions.  PHP's request model, like HTTP, was originally designed to be stateless.  Each request comes into the system with, and only with, information from the user.  As the language (and the web) moved towards being an application platform, a system that allowed information to be persisted was introduced to replace the homegrown systems that were cropping up.  This system was called sessions.  PHP sessions work by exposing a super global $_SESSION array to the end-user-programmer that allow information to be stored on a per web-user basis.  Sessions are implemented by setting a unique ID as a cookie on the user end, and then using that cookie as a lookup key (also standard practice for web applications)

In turn, the Magento system builds an abstraction on top of PHP's session abstraction.  In Magento, you can create a "session model" that inherits from a base session class, set data members on it, and save/load those data members just as you would with a database persistence model.  The difference is information is stored in the session instead of the database store. When you see

```
core/session
customer/session
```

these are two different session models, with each one storing different data. One belongs to the Mage_Core module, the other belongs to the Mage_Customer model.  This systems allows modules to safely set and manipulate their own session data, without accidentally stepping on another module's toes, and provide logical class methods for manipulating that data.

Hopefully that answers the questions you asked, as well as the ones you didn't.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply so fully. That was very informative.

Comment: Alan, great explanation - but the info about an initial call to getSingleton() followed by calls to getModel() is not quite accurate. In violation of the Singleton pattern, the second call (to getModel()) in a given execution scope will return a completely new instance. Subsequent calls to getSingleton() however will return the object singleton as described.

Comment: Weird, not sure how I got that bit of (wrong) of singleton voodoo in my head.  Text corrected.

Comment: Geez, wish I had have been able to read this a few years ago when I first started working with Magento.  Great write-up Alan.

Comment: @sdek I wish I'd been able to read it a few years ago as well!

Comment: I read this answer and halfway through thought 'Who the hell would know this much about Magento?' and of course I was not surprised when I saw the answerer's identity.  Great answer.

Comment: @AlanStorm Great answer! Small nitpicky detail though: the superglobal isn't called `$SESSIONS` but `$_SESSION`.

Answer (score 11):

1. Magento's getSingleton is almost the same as getModel. The difference is getModel always returns a new instance of a class, and getSingleton creates a new instance of a class only once and then always returns this instance. See the `Mage::getSingleton` and `Mage::getModel` methods. 
   Magento knows about looking to the Model folder because of configs in the `config.xml` file (f.e. `Mage/Customer/etc/config.xml`). See the [Magento wiki for developers](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/All%20Categories?idx=5_-_modules_and_development) to know more about config files.
2. You do not specify customer directly. It's done automatically by Magento in parent classes of `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` (see `Mage_Core_Model_Session_Abstract_Varien::start()` method)
3. Magento has not one session class to discriminate session data. For example, customer ID is stored in `Mage_Customer_Model_Session` and error flash message 'Product is not available' will be stored in the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Session` class.