# Magento's getItemsCollection is not applying filters

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I'm trying to apply filter to the quote items collection, i get the collection using this

```
$items_collection = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
$items_collection->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $_product->getId());
```

when i print out the select query, the query is correct

```
$items_collection->getSelect()
```

But when i iterate through the collection, it is fetching all of the items, it did not apply the filter, does anyone know why?

```
foreach ($items_collection as $item) {
    // Do things....
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use getModel instead of getSingleton.

```
$items_collection = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
$items_collection->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $_product->getId());

foreach ($items_collection as $item) {
echo $item->getProduct()->getId();
}
```

Comment: This works! Can you help explain the difference between the 2 getSingleton and getModel and how this helped solve the issue? I'm trying to understand Magento better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check app/Mage.php for getModel and getSingleton you can see difference. Mage::getModel() will always return a new Object for the given model. Mage::getSingleton() will check whether the Object of the given model already exists and return that if it does. You have created Singleton Object on which addFieldToFilter is not apply. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049575/magento-getsingleton-confusion.